# Getting HP dragonfly G4 to work under linux : virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, audio, webcam

I just got a "HP Dragonfly 13.5 inch G4 Notebook PC" without operating system hoping to run some flavor of GNU/Linux on it. I've tried Ubuntu 22.04 and Manjaro but both seem to have similar issues. Here I'm trying to adresse the problems with virtualization.

I use regularly a windows virtual machine in VirtualBox but I cannot get it to start on this computer. Starting initially stuck at 20%, following [this thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=108948) I tried to add ibt=off to the kernel default options but it still is stuck at 20%.

Comment: You need to manually sign the unsigned virtual drivers from Virtualbox. In Debian/Ubuntu we'd use `MOKutil`. Please do your own research for Manjaro. Meanwhile please use [edit] to update your questions, not the answers field for things that AREN'T answers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Excuse me Sir but what I posted as an answers solves my issue and I needed not to manually sign the unsigned virtual divers from Virtualbox as you suggested. I mentionned in my answer, the installation of virtualbox-host-dkms and reloading the kernel modules was the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to kernel 6.1.44-1-MANJARO then installing virtualbox-host-dkms :

```
yay -S virtualbox-host-dkms
```

And reloading kernel modules :

```
sudo /sbin/vboxreload
```

It initially kind of start but I only got a useless blinking cursor.

I finally copied again the VirtualBox folder from my former machine (the local one was likely damaged with the former trials), and now it starts ok :-)

Note : I previously used kernel 6.4 and not the current 6.1 as I was trying to improve the handling of the sound.

Comment: Updates to your question should be added to the question. This is not a forum with threaded conversations. This area is reserved only for answers. You can post your own answer, but it should actually solve the problem.

Comment: @music2myear Excuse me but this actually solves the problem. That is why I posted it as an answer. I will reformulate it to make it clearer

Comment: Ah, yes, now it does more clearly indicate your problem is resolved. Glad you figured it out, and that you shared what you figured out here.